# How to block iframes in Google Chrome Extension

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension

Google Chrome have option to disable flash and java and only run them on user click, how to create extension that will do this?

Comment: Do you want to know if the Chrome API has the capability to do this, or do you just want to know if such an extenstion exists? The first option is on-topic, but the second is not. I'd suggest you modify your question to ask the first question (but it can still include the second as a secondary question).

Comment: @RobW True, I can definitely appreciate your point, but the question as currently written could be answered perfectly with "no, there is no such extension" or "yes, here's a link" without mentioning Chrome's extension API at all. I don't merely intend to nitpick; I think a more precise wording would prevent well-meaning off-topic answers.

Comment: @apsillers Ok changed, but I wanted to know if there exist something like this, if not I will create it but I will find it in documentation, I was asking because I din't want to waste my time if there is something like this already, and searching for it didn't give any results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can implement this feature using the [`onBeforeRequest` event](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeRequest) of the [`webRequest` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest). Create a filter with `type: ['sub_frame']`, and extraInfoSpec `['blocking']`. Then, return `{cancel:true}` in the event listener.

Minimal example:

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {
    // Save the data in `details` for later use
    // The data must be associated with the `tabId` and `frameId`, so that it
    //  can be used later
    if (your_method_says_block_it())
       return {cancel: true};
}, {
    urls: ['*://*/*'],
    types: ['sub_frame']
}, ['blocking']);
```

Manifest file:

```js
 ...
    "permissions": ["webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "*://*/*"]
 ...
```

- The `webRequest` permission is needed to enable the API.
- The `webRequestBlocking` permission is needed to make the request handling synchronous, to enable the function to modify (cancel) the request.
- The `*://*/*` permission is needed to allow access to the host

Comment: Thanks for your answer I changed the quetion to match it, so others can benefit. But I just wanted to know if there is something like this already, probably with nice features, that I will not want to build.

Comment: Update: The [RequestFilter](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#type-RequestFilter) passed as the second argument to `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener` should pass in `types:` not `type:`.

Comment: @Peter Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Just try adblock or disable the desired content under chrome://settings/content