# Chrome extension "Uncaught error: Invalid value" using the redirect rules

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to write an extension that will download audio files when it detects them being requested by chrome.  I am basing this project on the code of the two samples "Download_links" and "catifier" provided by Google.  Here is what I currently have:

```
var RequestMatcher = chrome.declarativeWebRequest.RequestMatcher;
var IgnoreRules = chrome.declarativeWebRequest.IgnoreRules;
var RedirectRequest = chrome.declarativeWebRequest.RedirectRequest;
var songFileURL = "http://somefile.mp3";
...
function registerRules() {
    var redirectRule = {
    priority: 100,

    conditions: [
        new RequestMatcher({
            contentType: ['audio/mp3']
        }),
    ],

    actions: [
        chrome.downloads.download({url: songFileURL}),
    ]
};
...
```

When I load this up and try it out, I get an error: `Uncaught Error: Invalid value for argument 1. Property '.0': Value does not match any valid type choices.`  No matter what I try I cannot figure out what is causing this error.  I am fairly to Chrome extensions and JavaScript in general, so I am sure that this is an easy fix, but I cannot figure it out.  Any ideas?

Comment: Which line causes the eror `Uncaught Error: Invalid value for argument 1. Property '.0': Value does not match any valid type choices.`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you specify unsupported action. The list of available actions can be found on [the `chrome.declarativeWebRequest` page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeWebRequest.html#evaluation).

I think you should use `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest`, `onHeadersReceived`, or `onComplete` to trace media links and initiate custom downloads from there, possibly in some deferred way, because I'm not sure `downloads` will work just from another request handler.

To make a start you may have a look at Google's [CatBlock](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples.html#12a7bf1490a26359eadf10917e37c5b9) example, or to another [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12162257/1102014) or [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13571375/1102014). Basically, you need to add appropriate event handler by means of `addListener`, and in the handler invoke `chrome.downloads.download({url: request.url})`, where the `request` is passed to the handler as input parameter.

Which one of events to choose (for example, `onBeforeRequest` or `onComplete`) you should decide based on your requirements. As I understand, you don't want to block original request, so it may be useful to wait utill original downloading is completed, and then process it in `onComplete` handler, so that Chrome would optimize the process by just copying already downloaded file from cache.

As alternative, you can block initial download by returning `{cancel: true}` from `onBeforeRequest` handler for every sound file, and then start your download as a single one, possibly with `saveAs` option involved.